# updating time of datetime field using linq

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have two fields in my database for storing starttime and endtime. they are of datetime. I pick time from them using tostring("hh:mm tt"). Now I want to update only the time part of the date. I have dropdownlist to select hour and minutes and AM/PM. How can I update the time of date stored in sql server using Entity framework / LINQ in MVC3 application.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you don't really need to touch the linq part of this, basically what you want to do is just to convert the string back to a [datetime object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) and just manipulate the datetime object by either creating a new datetime object or add/minus mm/dd/yy hours or minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You must always update the whole datetime - it means you must build a new `DateTime` in your application and use correct Date part and defined Time part.

Answer (score 0):

create new DateTime Object

```
 DateTime mydate = New DateTime(2011, 6, 1, 12, 30, 0);
```

or

```
DateTime mydate = DateTime.Parse("2011-06-1 12:30:00 PM");
```